# Concatenate in Angular HTML Input Variables

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

How do I concatenate strings in Angular HTML Input? The following is creating dropdown.
What we want is have txtField be concatenation of addressCode + ' ' + addressDescription,  trying placing into input, did not work.
Looking for way in html first, before trying in angular typescript if possible.

**Original:**

```
<app-drop-down 
  [listItems]="'addressList'"
  [txtField]="'addressCode'"
  [txtValue]="'addressId'"
</app-drop-down>
```

Attempt

```
<app-drop-down 
  [listItems]="'addressList'"
  [txtField]="'addressCode' + 'addressDescription'"
  [txtValue]="'addressId'"
</app-drop-down>
```

Comment: concatenate in the .ts file and pass the same

Comment: is `addressCode` and `addressDescription` are the value of input field?

Comment: Its working here. Can not reproduce the same. Check here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-favrt3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: hi @HarunurRashid  for some reason no, its going off values in an array, along with wrapper on material design angular input

Comment: addressCode and addressDescription are from input?

Comment: plus @HarunurRashid  you are using {{ }}

Comment: To echo some value, you have to use interpolation. right?

Comment: Check this, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-favrt3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

with input field, its working too :)

Comment: is there any alternative syntax in angular, may try those

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this -

```
<app-drop-down 
  [listItems]="addressList"
  txtField="{{addressCode + addressDescription}}"
  [txtValue]="addressId"
</app-drop-down>
```

But following way also should work , as you mentioned in your question.

```
<app-drop-down 
  [listItems]="addressList"
  [txtField]="addressCode + addressDescription"
  [txtValue]="addressId"
</app-drop-down>
```

Here is the demo - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-59242999
Hope this helps, Let me know still if it does not work for you.

Comment: ok, I see why now, can you create an addendum to your answer, I had single quotes for values in question, thanks

Comment: you mean addressCode and addressDescription are strings ? or variables ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create simply a function

in .ts

```
concateInput(str1, str2){
return str1.concat(str2);
}
```

and call it from .html

```
<app-drop-down 
  [listItems]="addressList"
  [txtField]="concateInput(addressCode, addressDescription)"
  [txtValue]="addressId"
</app-drop-down>
```

Comment: when a user clicks on dropdown add that element into the array and pass that array to convert into a string.